# Confusion about structure of a sentence- "I personally wish to be away from this kind of discussions with team."

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, adverbs

> I personally wish to be away from this kind of discussions with team.

Is the above statement grammatically correct? or should I say

> My personal wish to be away ...

or it should be structured differently?

---

P.S.:

Am I confusing between adjectives and adverbs?

Am I making a mistake in structuring the sentence?.

It would be helpful if someone sense my mistakes from the sentences above and advise me how to improvise better writings.

Comment: In my opinion "with team" is not grammatical, it should be either "the team" or "teams". By the way, I edited your question based on my inference, so please  improve my edit if you think I've changed your intended question.

Comment: @Cardinal There is nothing grammatical in either version.

Comment: @P.E.Dant What do you mean? Shouldn't there be any article before the noun "team"? I wasn't talking about the whole sentence.

Comment: @Cardinal I meant that neither _"I personally wish to be away from this kind of discussions with team"_ nor _"My personal wish to be away from this kind of discussions with team"_ is a grammatical sentence in English, even with the addition of the definite article before "team".

Comment: @Cardinal -  you rephrased my question correctly, Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your meaning would be mostly understood, but you do make a couple of grammatical errors.

> I personally wish to be away from this kind of *discussion* with *the*
>   team.

**discussion** should be singular since with **kind of** you're referring to the class noun not to a set of instances:

I like the leaves of that *kind of tree*.

And you need the definite article before **team**.

The meaning of **be away from** is not perfectly clear.

One assumes you mean that you do not wish to be personally involved in those discussions with the team. You wish to absent yourself from those discussions.

But it might be taken to mean that you would like the team itself to steer clear of such discussions, that the team should not  discuss a particular topic, perhaps because it is outside their realm of responsibility or because it leads to  discord, whatever the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I got the need to use article and singular noun. but I wish to mean first one, can you suggest how this sentence need to be changed to convey the same?

Comment: @tech01230: You could say it in many ways. "I would prefer not to be there when the team is discussing such matters"  or "...when the team is having that kind of discussion"